# How can I improve the performance of a react three fiber?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

First of all, I'm sorry I'm not good at English.

i use react and I made a 3d rendering component by loading the obj file

(My source is attached below.)


my problem is below

3D object is rendered in 3 seconds.

However, for about 8 seconds after rendering, it stutters even when dragging, and other screens stutter.

After 8 seconds, dragging does not stumble and the buttons on the screen are clicked well.

What can I do to shorten the stuttering time like this?


Hope you share the wisdom of the teachers, thank you in advance

```
import React, {useMemo, useRef, useEffect, useState, Suspense} from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {Canvas, useFrame, useGraph, useLoader, useThree, createPortal, ObjectMap} from "@react-three/fiber";
import {OrbitControls, OrthographicCamera, useCamera, Html, useProgress, Stats, Center} from "@react-three/drei";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {OBJLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'
import {CameraControls, CameraControlsType} from "./cameraControls";
import LightController from "./lightController";
// @ts-ignore
import objectImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/NT_NO061.obj';
import aoMapImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/Textures/T_NT_NO061_AO.png';
import mapImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/Textures/T_NT_NO061_D.png';
import normalMapImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/Textures/T_NT_NO061_N.png';
import roughnessMapImage from 'assets/images/NT_NO061/Textures/T_NT_NO061_R.png';

type geometryType = {
    attach: string,
    vertices: any,
    onUpdate: any
}

type flag = {
    video: boolean,
    minimap: boolean
}

const Wrapper = styled.div`
    canvas {
        height: 594px
    }
`

const ReactThreeFiber = () => {
    const cameraControls = useRef<CameraControlsType | null>(null) as any;
    const [aoMap, map, normalMap, roughnessMap] = useLoader(THREE.TextureLoader, [
        aoMapImage,
        mapImage,
        normalMapImage,
        roughnessMapImage
    ])

    const [progressValue, setProgressValue] = useState<number>(0);
    const scene = useLoader(OBJLoader, objectImage, loader => {
        loader.manager.onProgress = (url, loaded, total) => {
            console.log('url, loaded, total', url, loaded, total)
        }
    }) as any;
    
    const {nodes} = useGraph(scene) as ObjectMap;
    const {geometry} = useMemo(() => nodes[Object.keys(nodes)[0]] as any, []);
    const material = useMemo(() => new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
        aoMap,
        map,
        normalMap,
        roughnessMap,
        roughness: 0.5,
        metalness: 0.80
    }), [])

    let startPoint = 3
    const lookAtPos = new THREE.Vector3()

    const rotate = () => {
        cameraControls.current.rotate(Math.PI / 4, 0, true)
    }

    const reset = () => {
        cameraControls.current.reset(true);
    }

    const startVideo = () => {
        cameraControls.current.reset(true);
    }

    return (
      <Wrapper>
          <Canvas
            camera={{position: [3, 3, 3]}}
            onCreated={({scene}) => scene.background = new THREE.Color('#000')}
            frameloop={'demand'}
          >
              <CameraControls
                ref={cameraControls}
                minDistance={2}
                maxDistance={7}
              />
              <LightController/>
              <OrbitControls/>
              <Center>
                  <mesh
                    position={[0, -2, 0]}
                    geometry={geometry}
                    material={material}
                  />
              </Center>
              <Stats/>
          </Canvas>
      </Wrapper>
    );
}

export default React.memo(ReactThreeFiber);
```

and "CameraControls" components codes

```
/* eslint-disable */
import React, { forwardRef, ForwardedRef, MutableRefObject, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import {
    MOUSE,
    Vector2,
    Vector3,
    Vector4,
    Quaternion,
    Matrix4,
    Spherical,
    Box3,
    Sphere,
    Raycaster,
    MathUtils,
} from 'three';
import { ReactThreeFiber, extend, useFrame, useThree } from '@react-three/fiber';
import CameraControlsDefault from 'camera-controls';

declare global {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            cameraControlsDefault: ReactThreeFiber.Node<CameraControlsDefault, typeof CameraControlsDefault>;
        }
    }
}

const subsetOfTHREE = {
    MOUSE: MOUSE,
    Vector2: Vector2,
    Vector3: Vector3,
    Vector4: Vector4,
    Quaternion: Quaternion,
    Matrix4: Matrix4,
    Spherical: Spherical,
    Box3: Box3,
    Sphere: Sphere,
    Raycaster: Raycaster,
    MathUtils: {
        DEG2RAD: MathUtils.DEG2RAD,
        clamp: MathUtils.clamp,
    },
};

CameraControlsDefault.install({ THREE: subsetOfTHREE });
extend({ CameraControlsDefault });

type PropsType = {
    minDistance: number,
    maxDistance: number
}

export const CameraControls = forwardRef<CameraControlsDefault, PropsType>((props, ref) => {
    const { minDistance, maxDistance } = props;
    const cameraControls = useRef<CameraControlsDefault | null>(null);
    const { camera, gl } = useThree();

    useFrame((_, delta) => {
        cameraControls.current?.update(delta)
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        if (cameraControls != undefined && cameraControls.current != undefined) {
            cameraControls.current.minDistance = minDistance;
            cameraControls.current.maxDistance = maxDistance;
        }
        return () => cameraControls.current?.dispose()
    }, []);

    return (
      <cameraControlsDefault
        ref={mergeRefs<CameraControlsDefault>(cameraControls, ref)}
        args={[camera, gl.domElement]}
      />
    );
});

export type CameraControlsType = CameraControlsDefault;

function mergeRefs<T>(...refs: (MutableRefObject<T> | ForwardedRef<T>)[]) {
    return (instance: T): void => {
        for (const ref of refs) {
            if (typeof ref === 'function') {
                ref(instance);
            } else if (ref) {
                ref.current = instance;
            }
        }
    };
}
```